# YouTube Video Feed in JSON into table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, url

How to get the youtube videos in JSON formate for list in `UITableView`. I need At a time 20 feeds to be listed and in show more button then next 20 results needed to display.

I am expecting the exact url to get the feeds in both case.

Now i am trying Url i give as example.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index=11&max-results=20&v=2&alt=jsonc
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index=2&max-results=20&v=2&alt=jsonc
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code parse YouTube JSON to table view.

[image: ss]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.row < [[_JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.title"] count]) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = 
        [[_JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =
        [[_JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.description"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The code to get JSON is below:

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kStrJsonURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id getJSON) {
        _JSON = getJSON;
        NSLog(@"%@", _JSON);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];        
}
```

You should read getting started about AFNetworking:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

You can download sample project from GitHub and just run it:

https://github.com/weed/p120805_YouTubeJsonParse

Comment: friend, can u show me how to send this request in simple way to server. you given example is soo wierd.

Comment: I tried several times to make HTTP request by standard functions like `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`, but these ways are very painful for me. At last, I decided to use the network library `AFNetworking`, with which you can get JSON in a few lines of code.

Comment: sorry friend i am illiterate with iphone coding. please help me what is the way to request AFNetworking. please give me the code.

Comment: I added the code to get JSON. I also simplified the GitHub sample. And write the URL for getting started page. I expect your fight.